# Java HashMap print separate values only one time

Tags: java, hashmap

hashmap key includes registration number and hashmap value includes owners name. Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

    data.put("AAA-111", "Jack");
    data.put("BBB-222", "Matt");
    data.put("CCC-333", "Jack");

    for (HashMap.Entry<String, String> entry: data.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(entry.getValue());
        //data.values().remove(entry.getValue());
    }
}
```

And the current output:

```
Jack
Matt
Jack
```

The problem is that I don't want to print out same owner two times. My goal output is:

```
Jack
Matt
```

How I can print same values only one time?

Comment: Add names to set (it will remove duplicates) and print set content...

Answer (score 8):

You can create a `Set` like this :

```
Set<String> names = new HashSet<>(data.values());
```

---

**Outputs**

```
[Matt, Jack]
```

Comment: I think this is the easiest (and most readable) way to do it. Use a `TreeSet` if you want the values sorted.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do that would be with Streams:

```
data.values().stream().distinct().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: can directly take .values()

Comment: This is a way to do it but I wouldn't call it "the easiest way".

Answer (score 2):

**1**. With  `Streams` to obtain a `List` or a `Set` :

```
// 1 list
List<String> list = data.values().stream()
                        .distinct().collect(Collectors.toList()); //[Jack, Matt]
// 2 set
Set<String> set = data.values().stream()
                      .distinct().collect(Collectors.toSet()); //[Matt, Jack]
```

**2**. Without  `Streams` to obtain a basic or sorted `Set` :

```
// 1 simple Set
Set<String> set = new HashSet<>(data.values()); //[Matt, Jack]
// 2 sorted Set
Set<String> set = new TreeSet<>(data.values()); //[Jack, Matt]
```

Answer (score 1):

It also can be done like this using `Map::values` and `Stream::distinct`:

```
data.values().stream().distinct().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Nice. Did you just copy my answer?

Comment: No I didn't. Guess you had something different before.

Comment: @JuanCarlosMendoza this is not same he used `values` and not `entryset`

Answer (score 1):

HashMap maps *unique* keys with values, values may be duplicate. The `put()` method accepts two parameter first being the Key and second being the Value.

```
data.put("AAA-111", "Jack");
data.put("BBB-222", "Matt");
data.put("CCC-333", "Jack");
```

Now `data.put("BBB-222", "Jill");` will replace "Matt" and "BBB-222" will be mapped with "Jill".

To have unique elements you can use `Set` and add elements, it will not add duplicate element. If you are getting a HashMap then either you can use Stream API as mentioned in other answers to extract distinct values or you can iterate the HashMap `values()` and can keep on adding each value to `Set` (you can choose `HashSet` ,`TreeSet`). The duplicate values will be discarded and be added only once. Then you can iterate the set to read distinct elements.

Answer (score -1):

You must put like a key the owner and the code like a value.

The value of last owner overrides the last.